# Map and Set in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, set, hashtable

In my current  project,   I need  following  type of data structure

```
Map<String, Map<String,Set<String>>, Set<subscriber>>
```

As per my knowledge, Java does not support this kind of data structure (Kindly correct me if I am wrong). Or (you can suggest me “how can I achieve this data type of data structure in Java).

Is there any third party library, which supports above mentioned data structure and operations on it?

Comment: Can you describe a little more about what you want this datastructure to do? Maps have keys and values, so what's the third parameter?

Comment: Map<String, Map<String,Set<String>>, Set<subscriber>>. It mean that datastructure is Multi-valued. first two arguments are keys.

Comment: it will be better if you describe your functional requirement, the problem looks to be in the design you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want maps to act as keys in your data structure, then I think this is what you want:

```
static Map<String,Set<String>> makeUnmodifiable(Map<String,Set<String>> m) {
  Map<String,Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
  for (Map.Entry<String,Set<String>> entry : m.entrySet()) {
    map.add(entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableSet(entry.getValue()));
  }
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

static class Pair {
  final String first;
  final Map<String,Set<String>> second;
  Pair(String first, Map<String,Set<String>> second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second != null ? makeUnmodifiable(second) : null;
  }
  public void equals(Object o) {
    ...
  }
  public int hashCode() {
    ...
  }
}

Map<Pair,Set<Subscriber>> myMap;
```

Note that you MUST override equals and hashCode in the custom Pair class in order for this to work properly.

Comment: Oh dear god no, it's not. Using a mutable object as a key in a `Map` is an incredibly bad idea even with overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: Alex -he posted his comment about two keys after the fact, I didn't see it. Your edits make this *much* better; see the note I added to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A map is a `key/value` object, so you can't have a `Map<String, Map, Set>` to start.

Comment: that's what OP is saying _As per my knowledge, Java does not support this kind of data structure_

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution would be to create an object to house all of your information and then make a Map with key `String`and value `CustomObject`

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't supply a simple "Pair" class so you'd need to write a wrapper class and use it in your Map:

```
class Wrapper {
    public Map<String,Set<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
    public Set<Subscriber> mySet = new TreeSet<Subscriber>();
}

Map <String, Wrapper> myMapOfWrappers = new HashMap<String, Wrapper>();
```

(The `Wrapper` class here is a simple example, you could provide getters/setters, etc as appropriate for your use case)

**Edit to add:** You added a comment under your question at the same time I posted this. Even though you accepted it as the answer, your comment says you are looking for *two keys*. You may want to rethink how you're approaching the problem. Alex shows in his example how you'd have to do this. Using mutable data as a key in a `Map` can cause a lot of problems should the contents change, which is what all his code is preventing. Implementing a `equals()` and `hashCode()` to prevent that is often not trivial.

Comment: Oh downvoter, please share your wisdom. (Apparently someone is internet hurt)

Comment: Agreed, the fact that you want to use maps as keys in another map is very unusual and seems to indicate maybe you don't completely understand the problem space, or are conflating some unrelated ideas. Maybe you'd be better off teasing this out into two maps or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

why not:

```
Map<String, Object[]>
```

and then create a 2 length object array to hold your `Map<String,Set<String>>` and `Set<subscriber>`

It's a bit of a hack, but it's a solution

EDIT: I like the custom object idea, way better and more type safe!

Comment: No helpful typing there. Why not use a pair-type type, either generic or custom-made for this purpose.